Boolean Difference not showing
I know this is an often question. I tryed several solutions from other threads, but it didn't work so far. Also lots of shortcuts mentioned as solutions don't seem to work. Don't know if that's because of a different version, if the questions are older.
I'm very new to blender and did a tutorial to create a lion head. I wanted to cut a hohle in the back for wall hanging, bit the boolean difference does not work. The cutting of the back of the head was done in sculpt mode with the cutting box tool, as boolean for that also already didn't work. But maybe that created the problem?
The difference doesn't work on any other parts of the lion either, though.
I checked for manifolds. There was a tincy selection I deleted, but nothing changed.


As answer pointed out try switching between fast and exact solvers in modifier whenever boolean misbehaves

@BenedictsForester As my answer tries to point out, it is impossible to see if the modifier works or not in this screenshot, since the sphere is hiding the result.

The Boolean modifier has no shortcuts, unless you have the BoolTool add-on enabled. So for this part it's less a question of the version you are using but what add-ons you have enabled.
For your problem: sometimes the Solver set to Fast works better than Exact (although the name might suggest otherwise), have you tried this?
But: are you sure it is not working? Because the sphere object is set to be visible, so it will obstruct the hole created by the modifier. The BoolTool add-on automatically changes the visibility of the cutter object to wireframe or bounding box or whatever, so it does not obstruct the view.
The tool also has a destructive method where the modifier automatically gets applied and the cutter object deleted, which also gets rid of the sphere obstructing the view. But nothing of this happens automatically if you add the modifier manually, to see the effect you will have to either make the sphere invisible or apply the modifier and delete the sphere.
Boolean modifier with sphere visible in viewport:

Boolean modifier with sphere invisible in viewport:


I meant shortcuts for other things that were suggested as maybe solving the problem for other people. But I don't know if I was always in the right mode. I usually check that though, when it's not working.
As for my probem: I have tried fast mode, I have tried to apply, but nothing happens (I found an error note, though. It says: Modyfier disabled, failed to apply. Don't know where it is supposed to be disabled.)
Making the sphere invisible just makes the sphere invisible, no hole.

@Schneeleopard The error usually comes when a modifier is set to something which does not change anything on the object, for example when a Subdivision Surface modifier is set to Levels 0, it de facto does not subdivide anything so it is disabled. In this case, the modifier icon will show red. A Boolean modifier will show this message when no other object is selected, but this is not the case in your screenshot and the icon is not red either. So if it's nothing of that, I guess you will have to upload your file for further inspection - because in the screenshot everything looks fine.

OK, thanks for trieng to help. I ended up loading an older save file and for some reason boolean worked with that one. For both cutting the backside as well as putting a hole into it. I don't know what I did wrong the first time.

@Schneeleopard We would probably know, so it might still be interesting to inspect the file to avoid similar problems in the future.
